# Unity cannot change material at runtime by script

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader-graph, urp

**Goal**

I created a shader graph that I use in a material "TestMaterial".
I have a game Object with a sprite renderer component with a default material property.

At runtime when user click on a simple button I want to change my gameObject > Sprite renderer > Material property "default" with my new material "TestMaterial".

**Context**

I use Universal Render Pipeline and Unity 2019.4.12.f1.
My code worked well before I use the function Edit > render pipeline > universal render pipeline > 2D renderer > Update project to 2d renderer.

**Tests I made**
My "TestMaterial" work well in editor and also at runtime when my gameobject use directly this material.
"TestMaterial" doesn't work only if I update material in my script, my gameObject keep old default material.

**Code**

```
[SerializeField] Material testMaterial;
[SerializeField] Material defaultMaterial;

public void UpdateToDefaultMaterial()
{
   this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material = defaultMaterial;
}

public void UpdateToTestMaterial()
{
   this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().material = testMaterial;
}
```

**Screenshot**
[Unity Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RszQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved my problem using an animator with a looping animation in which I change my material :

[GameObject Sprite renderer Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiIvD.jpg)

[Animation where I update material](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG8ON.jpg)

I still don't know why my animation works and not my code but It do the job... I will be happy if someone finds the answer for my culture...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Made sure you can replace it properly in the editor
2. I don't think sprite editors can use materials. Use a different kind of object to put the material on

Comment: It works well in editor I can replace material on inspector and my material with shader graph is Ok even when I run the game. But if i change material in my script at runtime with my method "UpdateToTestMaterial" it doesn't work anymore.